# How to work on outbox pattern using debezium?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, debezium

Do anybody has a good link to create outbox patten using debezium ?

Steps mentioned in below URL is not seems to be working .

https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/outbox

Error Trace :

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Debezium Outbox Demo - Build Aggregator 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] Debezium Outbox Demo - Build Aggregator ............ SUCCESS [  1.729 s]
[INFO] Debezium Outbox Demo - Order Service ............... FAILURE [ 43.897 s]
[INFO] Debezium Outbox Demo - Shipment Service ............ FAILURE [ 45.137 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  48.723 s (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-06T01:04:50+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.12.0.Final:build (default) on project outbox-order-service: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find the `native-image` in the GRAALVM_HOME, JAVA_HOME and System PATH. Install it using `gu install native-image`
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.getNativeImageExecutable(NativeImageBuildStep.java:627)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.getNativeImage(NativeImageBuildStep.java:343)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:112)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:920)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.12.0.Final:build (default) on project outbox-shipment-service: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find the `native-image` in the GRAALVM_HOME, JAVA_HOME and System PATH. Install it using `gu install native-image`
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.getNativeImageExecutable(NativeImageBuildStep.java:627)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.getNativeImage(NativeImageBuildStep.java:343)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:112)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:920)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn  -rf :outbox-order-service

Comment: Can you expand a bit what exactly isn't working in that example?

Comment: @Gunnar Updated the error trace

Answer (score 0):

All the information is actually in the error message:

> Cannot find the native-image in the GRAALVM_HOME, JAVA_HOME and System PATH. Install it using gu install native-image

You're trying to build the application as a GraalVM native binary, but don't have the required tooling installed for that. So either install the native-image tool (see the related Quarkus [guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image) for details), or build as a JVM application instead (by setting `QUARKUS_BUILD` to `jvm`).